# How to save filtered logcat content to a file?

Tags: android, adb

I used the command `adb logcat | findstr myString` to filter the logs from the command line and I could see the filtered logs. Now when I tried to save the logs in a file, I used `adb logcat | findstr myString > a.txt`. The **a.txt** file that is getting created is empty. What could be the reason for it and how would I save those filtered logs to a file from the command line ?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? https://askubuntu.com/a/731237

Comment: Most of these don't work in Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: Why are you using the windows command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

**Proper way to save output from LogCat into a file from command line:**

`adb logcat -d | findstr myString > logcat.txt.`

**From adb logcat --help**

`-d              Dump the log and then exit (don't block)`

**Since LogCat can get pretty large very quickly you may want to clear it every once in a while, you can do this easily from Eclipse or from a terminal window using the command:**

`adb logcat -c`